# Is it possible for multiple VMs (in Virtual Box) to use the same CPU core?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, cpu

I have 16gb of RAM and an Intel quad core processor that supports virtualization.

The host OS is Windows 10 Pro, 64 bit.

I want to run several Ubuntu 16.04 x32 guests, each doing very little work.

I planned on allotting 1gb of RAM each, but can they share cores?

Comment: Dunno about Windows as a host, but I've run 12 vms at once on my Linux desktop, 4 cores 8gb ram.  Allocated 512mb per vm (emulating internet, with multiple mail servers, dns servers, web servers, etc talking to each other).

Answer (score 2):

Even though you have only 4 cores, you are not limited to just 4 virtual machines. Virtual Box will create a process for each virtual machine, and then your operating system will handle scheduling them on the cores, just like any other process.

As you add virtual machines, your cpu cores will get progressively busier, though as the virtual machines are lightweight, you can probably add quite a few before running into performance issues, as long as you have memory to spare.